# standardising date format in excel

Tags: excel, date, formatting, vba

I have dates that look like this in a single column:

```
01-01-2017
04.2.2017
1-02-2017
2.02.2017
```

I want to standardize them to make them look like this:

```
01-01-2017
04-02-2017
01-02-2017
02-02-2017
```

Right now I achieve the desired result by selecting `"Text to Columns">"Delimited">Tab">"Date"`. But I have to do this each time I add data to my database which is once a day!

Is there a formula i could use or vba code to do this for me?

Note 1 - using "Format Cells" did nothing hence the "Text to Columns" approach.

Note 2 - this is how I'm copying and pasting the data from one workbook to another...

```
'copy range from target workbook
 vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(Sheet.Name).Range("b3:i102")

'paste the data and then add a column with the demo "TOTAL" next to it
sht1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the date to the database? It should be possible to modify this code so that it adds a date and not a string.

Comment: see update.....

Comment: Are the dates in the sheet you are copying from stored as text or as dates?

Comment: mixed, some are dates some are text, hence i want to standardise them

Comment: Use the code I've added to my answer.

Comment: How did they get into that original worksheet (the one you are copying from) in a mixed text/real date format?  Did they perhaps originate in a text or csv file where the format is different from your windows regional date format?

Answer (score 0):

If the format cells is not working, its probably because they are stored as text rather than a date. If you change the column to date format (you may need to copy and paste the data (paste values)) it should fix it.

You can also change a text to a date with the VBA routine below:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.columns("A").Cells
    c.Value = DateValue(Replace(c.Value, ".", "/"))
Next c
```

Comment: The problem is the decimal points. The date conversion can cope with slashes and dashes but not the decimal points. So I added something to remove them before conversion. Do you have any other strange characters separating the dates?

Answer (score -1):

In the cells with the dates have tried to Find & Replace the "." with "/" ?

Then make sure that the column with the dates is formatted as: dd-mm-yyyy;@

Can write a macro to do this if it works.